# Ionic Screen Orientation Cordova Plugin is not locking to portrait mode in iOS environment

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework, screen-orientation

I'm using Ionic framework with the plugin `cordova-plugin-screen-orientation` and I would like to lock my app orientation to be always portrait.

I tried to do it by putting the next line in the `config.xml`

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

It works on `android` but not on `ios`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have both ios and android screen orientation plugin ?

Comment: You don't need a plugin for that, uninstall it and try again. Are you editing the root www folder? are you running the app from the CLI?

Answer (score 3):

I hope I'm not late.

You can do it easily but with a different Cordova plugin.

First you will need to use Cordova net.yoik.cordova.plugins.screenorientation plugin.

You can easily programmatically lock/unlock screen orientation using it.

```
// set to either landscape
screen.lockOrientation('landscape');

// allow user rotate
screen.unlockOrientation();
```

If you want to do this for all pages/views do it like this:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
   screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
});
```

Next, to do it only on selected pages, use this code inside an appropriate page controller:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function(){
    screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
});
```

If executed in a right controller this code will trigger orientation lock before the view becomes visible.

Read this if you want to find out more: http://www.gajotres.net/changing-locking-screen-orientation-in-ionic-application/

Comment: This is good, but the browser support isn't: http://caniuse.com/#feat=screen-orientation

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ionic/Capacitor and Vuejs, I also had the same problem with the plugin for iOS. This is what I did and it solved the problem.

**To fix the bug to be able to lock the screen to the specified orientation on iOS:**

**1.** Open AppDelegate.swift for your app. You can find this file inside ios/App/App/AppDelegate.swift

**2.** Add the following code:

```
var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return self.orientationLock
}

@objc func setOrientationLock(_ notification: Notification)
{
    if let data = notification.userInfo as? [String: Int]
    {
        for (_, mask) in data
        {
            switch mask
            {
                case 1: self.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
                break;
                case 2: self.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portraitUpsideDown
                break;
                case 3: self.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeRight
                break;
                case 4: self.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeLeft
                break;
                case 5: self.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape
                break;
                default: self.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**3.** In the same file locate: "func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {"

**4.** Add the following code inside the function before the "return true" statement:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.setOrientationLock), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "CAPOrientationLocked"), object: nil)
```

**5.** ionic build, ionic cap copy, ionic cap sync, and problem FIXED!